# What is a usage and purpose of Laravel's binding?

Tags: php, laravel

I cannot understand a point of Laravel's binding system. I know what does dependency injection mean. And it can work even without that weird "bindings", right? I saw in documentation, that binding can return a new object. Why and when I have to use that? Please, explain not very complicated, because I've read documentation and I could not understand the use and the purpose of that bindings. Thanks.

Comment: read this https://heera.it/laravel-repository-pattern#.VuJcVfl97cs

Answer (score 100, accepted):

> And it can work even without that weird "bindings", right?

Not really. Sure it can work just fine if the required dependencies are simple to instantiate. Let's say you have this simple class `Foo` stored in `app` directory:

```
<?php

namespace App;

class Foo
{
    public function hello()
    {
        return 'Hello World';
    }
}
```

You can type hinted this class without binding it first in the container. Laravel will still be able to resolve this class. Let's say you type-hinted it like this in the routes:

```
Route::get('/foo', function (App\Foo $foo) {
    return $foo->hello(); // Hello World
});
```

We can even go further, let's say this `Foo` class required another simple class `Bar`. Our `Bar` class looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App;

class Bar
{
    public function hello()
    {
        return 'bar';
    }
}
```

And our `Foo` class looks like this now:

```
<?php

namespace App;

class Foo
{
    public function __construct(Bar $bar)
    {
        $this->bar = $bar;
    }

    public function hello()
    {
        return $this->bar->hello();
    }
}
```

Will Laravel be able to resolve the type-hinted `Foo` class now? YES! Laravel will still be able to resolve this `Foo` class.

Now the issue will come in when our `Foo` class needs slightly more complex dependencies that need to be configured. Imagine that our `Foo` class simply need the name of our application. Sure you can simply use `config('app.name')` within the class's method, but imagine that this can be an HTTP client that requires a configuration array to instantiate.

```
<?php

namespace App;

class Foo
{
    public function __construct($appName)
    {
        $this->appName = $appName;
    }

    public function hello()
    {
        return "Hello {$this->appName}";
    }
}
```

Will Laravel be able to solve this class now? NOPE. [Service Container](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/container) to the rescue! You can teach Laravel how to resolve this `Foo` class by binding it in service container. You can define the binding within the `register` method on `app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php` file:

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind(\App\Foo::class, function ($app) {
        // Pass the application name
        return new \App\Foo($app->config['app.name']);
    });
}
```

And sometimes, you don't want multiple instances to be created. Like our `Foo` class for instance, there's no need for multiple instances for this kind of class. In this case, we can bind it with singleton method.

```
$this->app->singleton(\App\Foo::class, function ($app) {
    return new \App\Foo($app->config['app.name']);
});
```

**More Important Usage**

But the more important usage of this service container is that we can bind an interface to it's implementation. Let's say we have this `PaymentProcessorInterface` with `pay` method:

```
<?php

namespace App;

interface PaymentProcessorInterface
{
    public function pay();
}
```

Then we have the implementation of this interface named `StripeProcessor`:

```
<?php

namespace App;

class StripeProcessor implements PaymentProcessorInterface
{
    public function pay()
    {
        return 'pay with stripe';
    }
}
```

With service container, we can bind the `PaymentProcessorInterface` to `StripeProcessor` class:

```
$this->app->bind(\App\PaymentProcessorInterface::class, function () {
    return new \App\StripeProcessor();
});
```

We can then type-hinted `PaymentProcessorInterface` within our code:

```
Route::get('/pay', function (App\PaymentProcessorInterface $paymentProcessor) {
    return $paymentProcessor->pay(); // pay with stripe
});
```

This way we can easily swap the `PaymentProcessorInterface` implementation. Let's say we want to change the payment processor to Paypal then we have this `PaypalProcessor` class.

```
<?php

namespace App;

class PaypalProcessor implements PaymentProcessorInterface
{
    public function pay()
    {
        return 'pay with paypal';
    }
}
```

All we have to do is update the binding:

```
$this->app->bind(\App\PaymentProcessorInterface::class, function () {
    return new \App\PaypalProcessor();
});
```

Hope this gives you some ideas.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed tut :)

Comment: Official documentation should write people like you. Brilliant!

Comment: Perfect clap clap :)