# How $this->app->singleton() works in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

In my laravel project I have following interface, repository and controller.

This is Interface

```
interface TrainingClassTypeInterfaces
{
    public function updateTrainingClassType($id, $request);
}
```

This is Repository

```
use App\Models\Trainings\AppTrainingClassType;
class TrainingClassTypeEloquent implements TrainingClassTypeInterfaces
    {
        protected $model;
    
        public function __construct(AppTrainingClassType $appTrainingClassType)
        {
            $this->model = $appTrainingClassType;
        }
    
        public  function updateTrainingClassType($id, $request)
        {
            $response = false;
            $isUpdated = $this->model::where('training_class_id',$id)->update([
                'app_id' => $request->app_id
            ]);
            .... 
        }
    
    }
```

This is controller

```
class TrainingClassTypesController extends \TCG\Voyager\Http\Controllers\VoyagerBaseController
{
    protected  $trainingService;
    public function __construct(TrainingClassTypeEloquent $trainingClassTypeInterfaces) {
        $this->trainingService = $trainingClassTypeInterfaces;
    }

    public function insertOrUpdate()
    {
        ...
        $this->trainingService->updateTrainingClassType($id, $request);
        ..
    }

}
```

**Everything working fine till here**

As you can see I am using TrainingClassTypeEloquent's method inside `TrainingClassTypesController`. But it was returning error something like

`Argument 1 passed to ...::__construct() must be an instance of`

Basically it was asking me to put instance of Model into `TrainingClassTypeEloquent` class. Then I did as following

```
$TCTypes = new AppTrainingClassType();
$TCT = new TrainingClassTypeEloquent($TCTypes);
$TCT->updateTrainingClassType($id, $request);
```

which was working fine but I was confused that this approach is not proper, there should be some proper way.

After googling I found another solution which is singleton binding, and then I tried following in AppServiceProvider

```
$this->app->singleton(
            \App\Services\Voyager\Eloquent\TrainingClassType\TrainingClassTypeInterfaces::class,
            \App\Services\Voyager\Eloquent\TrainingClassType\TrainingClassTypeEloquent::class
        );
```

After adding this singleton binding, I notice script was working without providing model instance into `TrainingClassTypeEloquent` class.

I would like to know how `$this->app->singleton()` is working, so in this way my concept would be clear about it. If someone knows then kindly guide me about it.

Thank you so much

Comment: Use `TrainingClassTypeInterfaces $trainingClassTypeInterfaces` as an argument on the constructor method of the controller class instead of `TrainingClassTypeEloquent $trainingClassTypeInterfaces` to make it open for extension.

Answer (score 5):

It is all about **BINDING** a **service** to the [service container](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/container).

**What does `$this->app->singleton();` method do?**

The singleton method binds a class or interface into the [service container](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/container) so that Laravel can maintain dependency (when using an interface as the constructor parameter).

(Actually **Singleton** is a design pattern. Singleton implementation always returns the same object on subsequent calls instead of a new instance). So `$this->app->singleton();` method returns the same object again and again.

**Point to be noted** that Laravel doc says:

> There is no need to bind classes into the container if they do not
> depend on any **interfaces**. The container does not need to be instructed
> on how to build these objects, since it can automatically resolve
> these objects using reflection.

But your controller class depends on an interface, so the container needs to be informed and to do this, you need to use this `$this->app->singleton();` method but there are other ways around.

Again, at the same time, this `TrainingClassTypeEloquent::class` has a dependency of `AppTrainingClassType::class`. But in this case, we do not need to worry about that because Laravel uses [Reflection API](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) to maintain its dependency as this class does not use interface as like `TrainingClassTypesController::class` class.

Once you are done with binding the service to the container, Laravel will then automagically put the service onto the constructor method as an argument where the interface is used.

I hope this would help you. You may find more help from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49349349).

Comment: ```So $this->app->singleton(); method returns the same object again and again```. Does it mean that the singleton instance will remain between Requests. Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Yeah. You're right.

Comment: Why is it important that something like this has a `Singleton` ? What would be bad about instantiating another Object? I've seen this pattern in Laravel apps where a singleton doesn't seem necessary, but the pattern continues to be used. Thanks

Comment: If you DON'T need different states of an object then why would you create that object again and again taking more resources. Otherwise, some objects are expensive to be created, database connection, for example. It's a network call which is expensive. So caching the object makes better performance. You get the idea.

Answer (score 2):

You need to register TrainingClassTypeEloquent

```
$this->app->singleton(TrainingClassTypeInterfaces::class, static function ($app) {
    return new TrainingClassTypeEloquent(new AppTrainingClassType());
});
```

Then you can inject it in your Controller

```
public function insertOrUpdate(TrainingClassTypeInterfaces $trainingService, $id)
{
    $trainingService->updateTrainingClassType($id, request());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but as I mentioned I already founded and my script is already working I just want to know that how `$this->app->singleton()` it is working

Comment: So, you're looking for how does work Dependency Injection ? Here's a good read https://medium.com/a-young-devoloper/how-laravel-injects-our-dependencies-14e1b1a044e There is no sense to answer to this since there's already plenty of posts/answers about this.
Note: `Singleton` is a pattern to ensure that the object has only one instance of the class and this instance will be re-used everywhere it's called. There's also many place you can find more information.